# How to replace values in array b by indexes from array a ? [numpy]

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, python-2.7, python-3.7

For example, there is an array a.

```
a = [
        [1,2]
    ]
```

And array b.

```
b = [
        [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
    ]
```

How can I replace the values in array b with indexes from array a by 1  ?

That is, the following array r should be obtained.

```
r = [
        [[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
    ]
```

I have spent a lot of time solving this problem and have not found the fastest possible way without brute force.

Answer (score 1):

The following code perform indexing with broadcasting

```
import numpy as np
    

a = np.array( [
        [1,2]
    ])

b = np.array([
        [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
    ])
r = np.zeros(b.shape)
r[np.arange(a.shape[0]), np.array(a.shape ) -1, a] = 1

print(r)
```

> [[[0. 1. 0.]   [0. 0. 1.]]]

Comment: And if the size is any ? I get an error https://i.ibb.co/cJ1C1kH/2023-02-25-00-16-23.png